# ace-window: How can I switch to a frame I can't see?

Tags: frames, ace-window

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

When I want to switch between windows I user `M-x ace-window` and then select number. Nice.

But I also want to switch to a frame that isn't visible. I can guess what number to select, but that's difficult. Can I use `ace-window` to switch to a frame I can't see?

Comment: Isn’t it just the same?

Comment: @InHarmsWay Suppose I has 4 frames. Every frames split by 3 windows. How I can fast switch from frame#4 to frame#2?

Comment: Use ace-window to select a window on frame 2?  What about that doesn’t work for you?

Comment: @InHarmsWay it's work.. but I must remember what number is refer to what frame. I must guess. It's not very comfortable.

Comment: ace-window labels the windows for you, you don't need to remember any numbers. Just select the label for the window you want to go to: http://oremacs.com/download/ace-window.gif

Comment: Are you saying that frame 2 is not visible before you switch to it?

Comment: @InHarmsWay yes, when frame 2 is not VISIBLE I need to guess what number to select. It's not very comfortable.

Comment: I see. I never position my frames over one another so never have to deal with this issue. Have you tried ‘counsel-wmctrl, part of the counsel package, which under certain window managers might give you what you want.

Comment: Ace-window doesn’t have built-in support for this so you may need a custom command. How would you want it to work — if the frame is not visible you’ll need to remember some identifier for it? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900889/switch-between-frames-by-number-or-letter for one example.

Comment: If you generally have one frame visible at a time, another option might be to switch between sets of windows/buffers in a single frame, rather than between frames. For example the ivy package has `ivy-push-view` to save the current window layout as a named target you can switch back to later. This way you can jump between sets of related buffers easily.

Comment: @Alexei I edited your question to be a little bit more in line with your comments here. Feel free to edit further for clarity.